# how to change prompt size of textinput in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, command-prompt

I have created a spark text input component and I prompt a text in the text input using prompt property.
But the font size of prompt is very small.
How to change the font size of prompt....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Skin with host component as TextInput and set the fontSize of Label with id "promptDisplay". and apply this skin to TextInput